# What is the best way to load ASP page in my ASPX page?

Tags: asp.net, parsing, asp-classic

I'm working with a partner who gives me tools in Classic ASP.
My website is in ASP.NET 4.0, what is the best way to include its tools in my page?

I have a restriction, I can't enable Classic ASP on my server.

Is it possible to parse it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compile your classic asp code to .net using this compiler:

http://aspclassiccompiler.codeplex.com/

and then run that.

Or you can paste your file.asp contents into file.aspx and then modify the code until it compiles. Sometimes you can update the objects to the corresponding pure .net class or object, sometimes you have to use .NET's COM interop facilities. It is easier than it looks to do a single page, it is much, much harder than it looks to do an entire application with 100s of pages and a full set of classic asp patterns.

Comment: Can I add the Classic ASP code in my ASP.NET code programmaticaly?

Comment: Personally, I'm biased towards hand porting if the page is small enough. I have no personal experience with aspClassicCompiler but if I were to use it today, I'd use the compiler then decompile the results with reflector to see if I agree with how the aspClassicCompiler did it's porting.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run classic asp pages from a server w/o classic asp.

Can you put them on another server or something?

Comment: Doesn't the OS have built in support for classic ASP??

Comment: Classic ASP is no longer enabled by default on new servers, esp Windows 2008.

Comment: @MatthewMartin: Huh... interesting. I guess that makes sense since it's all but obsolete.

Comment: The real problem with legacy technologies is that they are often forgotten about, left enabled and become vectors for malicious code.

Answer (score 0):

Having a good amount of experience with this, I would suggest using `Server.Execute` to load the ASP page into a container on the ASPX page.

**EDIT**

> Error executing child request for test.asp. No http handler was found for request type 'GET'

Try adding this `httpModule` to your `web.config`:

```
<httpModules> 
    <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/> 
</httpModules>
```

Comment: This seems to be a good solution, but when I do that I get exception: **Error executing child request for test.asp.** _No http handler was found for request type 'GET'_

Comment: Are you trying to load this into an update panel or something?

Comment: With the HTTP Module I get an Interal Error **An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.** and yes I want to load that in a PlaceHolder for example